# Want to make email template from html string in react js

Tags: reactjs

```
const person = {
    name: 'Wes',
    job: 'Web Developer',
    city: 'Hamilton',
    bio: 'Wes is a really cool guy that loves to teach web development!'
}

const emailData = '<div class="person"><h2>${person.name}</h2><p class="location">${person.city}</p><p class="bio">${person.bio}</p></div>'
```

I have one object and that object data i want to bind with emailData.

My expectation is:-

```
<div class="person"><h2>Wes</h2><p class="location">Hamilton</p><p class="bio">Wes is a really cool guy that loves to teach web development!</p></div>
```

Comment: Please give your suggestion without using replace function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want an answer in React, this pattern you're describing is very easy to transform into a component:

```
function EmailData(props) {
  return <div className="person">
    <h2>{props.name}</h2>
    <p className="location">{props.city}</p>
    <p className="bio">{props.bio}</p>
  </div>
}
```

You would then call this like:

```
<EmailData name="Wes" city="Hamilton" bio="..." />
```

Or, if you already have the `person` object, you can use the spread operator:

```
<EmailData {...person} />
```